# Guice dependency issue

Tags: java, guice

I have some DAO class with 2 injected named instances:

```
@Inject
@Named("Name1")
DSLContext dsl1;

@Inject
@Named("Name2")
DSLContext dsl2;
```

and everything works fine. At the same time I want to use different class which has injected (not named) DSLContext in it's constructor:

```
DSLContext dslContext;

@Inject
CommonsPlayerTokensDaoImpl(DSLContext dslContext) {
    this.dslContext = dslContext;
}
```

and I want to use one of my existing contexts here. Of course, in this case Guice cannot automatically resolve the dependency. How can I do it ?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

Comment: `I want to use one of my existing contexts here` -> Which one, exactly? How/where do you make that decision?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Named` annotation with constructor's parameter: 
`@Inject 
CommonsPlayerTokensDaoImpl(@Named("Name1") DSLContext dslContext) {`

Comment: Yes, I can and I did it...but is it possible to inject specific instance WITHOUT changing the class which has a constructor ?

Comment: Next idea is to use method annotated with `@Provides` at your Guice Module: `@Provides
            public CommonsPlayerTokensDaoImpl provideCommonsPlayerTokensDaoImpl(@Named("Name2") DSLContext dslContext) {
                return new CommonsPlayerTokensDaoImpl(dslContext);
            }`